# The eigenvalue/singular values of (large) square random matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices, singular-values

$M$ is an iid random matrix with $M_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{g^2}N)$ except that the diagonal entries are $-1$.

I am to compute, *in the limit $N\to\infty$*,

1. the eigenvalue/singular value spectrum/distribution. I.e. we order the eigenvalues according to their relevant values such that $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \dots \ge \lambda_N$, and then we hope to know the mean of each $\lambda_i$) of a random matrix $M$:
   $$\bar \lambda_1, \bar\lambda_2, \dots, \bar \lambda_N.$$
2. the mean ($\ln$) thereof:
   $$\langle \ln \lambda \rangle = \frac{\ln\lambda_1 + \ln\lambda_2 + \dots + \ln\lambda_N}N.$$

It seems we can calculate $\langle \ln \lambda \rangle$ using $\det(M)$. Then how can we compute the determinant (also a statistics) of such a random matrix?

We possibly need to use the Wigner semicircular law.
 Possible methods in random matrices or more general probability include

> reductions, the Fourier method, the moment method, the Lindeberg swapping trick, individual  swapping, Stein's method, Predecessor comparison.

$\\$

I hope to know any **books or papers** about solving the above (or other) statistics of this (or **simpler** similar) random matrix, or of other 'symmetric' (w.r.t. probability distribution of each entry) matrices, or of other kinds of (large) square random matrices. **The literature of random matrices is vast so I hope to narrow down the scope of my research.** I can read them to find clues. Exact solutions are welcome but not necessarily expected right now.

---

This seems to be a seminal paper in the topic:
https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.60.1895

A closely related post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352559/spectrum-of-large-random-asymmetric-matrices-with-correlation

This is a simple example: [Determinant of a random matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114393/determinant-of-a-random-matrix), but it doesn't tell much about the statistics I would like to compute.

---

Appendix 1.

My thoughts about q1:
An idea might be to first calculate the probability density for the vector random variable:
$\rho_N ( \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_N),$
but $N\to\infty$ might complicate the issue of defining such a density.

About q2:
Perhaps since **sum of ln = ln of product, and product of eigenvalues = determinant**, the calculation might be thus simplified, as illustrated below.

---

Appendix 2.

(*This section is unnecessary for answering the question:*) An example of calculation is given as (note that $\mu_i$ below is actually eigenvalues (specifically, of an Oseledets matrix $\Lambda$) denoted as $\lambda_i$ above. I hope to know what is more general than the example):

> [image: a]

For this example in particular, why $$\prod_i \mu_i = \det(\Lambda)?$$

My thought is that we can transform $\Lambda$ to a diagonal matrix $D$ with a unitary matrix $P$:
$\Lambda = P D P^{-1},$ 
where $D_{ii} = \mu_i$ (or the eigenvalues in different order), $\det(P) = \det(P^{-1})=1$, and so
$$\det (\Lambda) = \det(P) \det (D) \det(P^{-1})=\det (D) =\prod_i \mu_i.$$

(In a word, the reason for the above step is that **the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix is always equal to the product of its eigenvalues, if the matrix has complete set of eigenvalues, i.e. #eigenvalues = $n$.** A related discussion is here: [Show that the determinant of $A$ is equal to the product of its eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507641/show-that-the-determinant-of-a-is-equal-to-the-product-of-its-eigenvalues))

Is it correct? (No need to answer this question here.)

Comment: 'by setting  to zero (simply because it is a variable) we get on the left side det(), and on the right side 12⋯'